# Magento 2.4.3: graphQL ResolveURL response error "Internal server error"

Tags: magento2, product, graphql, pwa

I am working on `Magento 2.4.3` setup graphQL with `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS` machine.
I setup a pwa-studio with `venia-concept` theme on the same machine and connected it with the Magento setup.

All is running good in PWA except the product details page is showing "Internal server erro"

When I checked the Network section then found that `graphQL` `ResolveURL` is throwing an error below:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Internal server error",
            "extensions": {
                "category": "internal"
            },
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 1,
                    "column": 75
                }
            ],
            "path": [
                "route",
                "type"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "data": {
        "route": {
            "relative_url": "black.html",
            "redirect_code": 0,
            "type": null,
            "id": 6857,
            "__typename": "SimpleProduct"
        }
    }
}
```

graphQL query is :

```
query ResolveURL($url:String!){route(url:$url){relative_url redirect_code type ...on CmsPage{identifier __typename}...on ProductInterface{id __typename}...on CategoryInterface{id __typename}__typename}}
```

Checked this graphQl on postman pointing to the same issue.

When I checked graphQL error in Magento Log:

```
[2021-12-07 04:37:58] main.ERROR: Expected a value of type "Int" but received: PRODUCT {"exception":"[object] (GraphQL\\Error\\Error(code: 0): Expected a value of type \"Int\" but received: PRODUCT at /var/www/html/mage0/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Error/Error.php:174, GraphQL\\Error\\InvariantViolation(code: 0): Expected a value of type \"Int\" but received: PRODUCT at /var/www/html/mage0/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php:976, GraphQL\\Error\\Error(code: 0): Int cannot represent non 32-bit signed integer value: PRODUCT at /var/www/html/mage0/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Type/Definition/IntType.php:62)"} []
```

Anyone has gone through this issue . please help.

Comment: I have faced this issue. The problem was with the backend url which was given in the .env file. So check that file. eg scenario: backend url: localhost/magento243 . This url will be used by the pwa studio to send graphql which appends "/graphql" in the url, which will be "localhost/magento243/graphql". So check whether this is working. And check the magento site is working. If not check with permissions..

Comment: thanks @Jason, I checked it many times, but the issue persist

Answer (score 1):

just Please Check if you have a product attribute with code type
and remove it and reindex and clear cache